# Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred when trying to start an IIS6 website

Tags: iis, iis-6, http

I'm trying to start an IIS website & I keep getting the error

> Unexpected error 0x8ffe2740 occurred

Investigating in the system log displays this error

> The service could not bind instance 1.  The data is the error code. 
>   For additional information specific to this message please visit the Microsoft Online Support site located at: http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

I have had WAMP running on this machine, but I shut it down & I can't see anything else that could be bound to port 80.  If I change the port to something else it works fine, so I am assuming it is because something else was bound to 80 and it hasn't been released, but I can't see what it is

Answer (score 1):

[Use netsta](http://www.petri.co.il/quickly_find_local_open_ports.htm)t or [ActivePorts](http://download.cnet.com/Active-Ports/3000-2651_4-29653.html?tag=mncol) to find if something is still holding on to port 80.

Comment: ActivePorts says there's nothing on Port 80

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: It's Windows XP SP2

Comment: Do you have Skype or anything like that running on it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ActivePorts, but make sure it checks on both the public and the loopback interface.

Comment: Yes, good call.  And make sure you're looking at the local port column.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a problem with [Skype](http://www.skype.com/) listening to port 80, if it was started while IIS was not. If Skype *is* taking over port 80, you can solve this problem changing a Skype setting:

```
File > Options > Connection
```

Uncheck *"Use Port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections."* You should be able to restart default website now.